# Using ionic nav-bar, google Maps object doesn't load Map object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with ionic, angularJS and Google Maps V3 API js and when I try to use the bar-navigation between different views, the google map doesn't load properly.

I have an intro, that has a button to open the view containing the map object, and when I touch on the button everything loads fine except the map.

```
 app.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
        });


        $scope.map = map;

        $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        //call it here
        var element = (document.getElementById('map'));
        var windowHeight = window.self.outerHeight;
        var finalHeight = windowHeight * 0.62;
        element.style.height = finalHeight+'px';
        });
    });
});
```

This code works fine if I put the view containing the map as the first view of my web application.
How can I load properly the map, or is there a way to preload all the views?

Comment: You view with map is visible at startup or hiddden?

Comment: if your map is initially hidden, then you have to trigger `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` manually. Also take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#event

Comment: my maps is not visible since I'm on another view (the introduction view).
How and where should I call the trigger function?

Comment: it is when you change your view to the page where the map is displayed